# FedEx WebService Sameday: Invalid Service Type

Tags: fedex

Integrating with FedEx web services, as part of "Ship Service" testing, when I use the "SAMEDAY" service type for shipment, getting a response as "Invalid service type".

Please find the below details:

1. Service URL - https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/ship
2. Attached

   - Payload
   - Response
3. In return, received "2464" error code and "Invalid service type" message

Payload:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v13">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ProcessShipmentRequest>
        <WebAuthenticationDetail>
            <UserCredential>
                <Key>YOUR ACCOUNT</Key>
                <Password>YOUR PASSWORD</Password>
            </UserCredential>
        </WebAuthenticationDetail>
        <ClientDetail>
            <AccountNumber>YOUR ACCOUNT</AccountNumber>
            <MeterNumber>YOUR METER</MeterNumber>
        </ClientDetail>
        <TransactionDetail>
            <CustomerTransactionId>J-0080000190-12345671000000128</CustomerTransactionId>
        </TransactionDetail>
        <Version>
            <ServiceId>ship</ServiceId>
            <Major>28</Major>
            <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
            <Minor>0</Minor>
        </Version>
        <RequestedShipment>
            <ShipTimestamp>2021-11-10T22:22:13-05:00</ShipTimestamp>
            <DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</DropoffType>
            <ServiceType>SAME_DAY</ServiceType>
            <PackagingType>YOUR_PACKAGING</PackagingType>
            <TotalWeight>
                <Units>LB</Units>
                <Value>39.683</Value>
            </TotalWeight>
            <Shipper>
                <AccountNumber>YOUR ACCOUNT</AccountNumber>
                <Contact>
                    <CompanyName>Company name</CompanyName>
                    <PhoneNumber>111111111 </PhoneNumber>
                    <EMailAddress>email@gmail.com</EMailAddress>
                </Contact>
                <Address>
                    <StreetLines>3240 BAYSHORE BLVD</StreetLines>
                    <City>BRISBANE</City>
                    <StateOrProvinceCode>CA</StateOrProvinceCode>
                    <PostalCode>94005</PostalCode>
                    <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                </Address>
            </Shipper>
            <Recipient>
                <Contact>
                    <PersonName>XYZ</PersonName>
                    <CompanyName>Domestic US Customer 11</CompanyName>
                    <PhoneNumber>11111111</PhoneNumber>
                </Contact>
                <Address>
                    <StreetLines>Augusta Ave SE</StreetLines>
                    <City>Atlanta</City>
                    <StateOrProvinceCode>GA</StateOrProvinceCode>
                    <PostalCode>30315-1402</PostalCode>
                    <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                </Address>
            </Recipient>
            <ShippingChargesPayment>
                <PaymentType>SENDER</PaymentType>
                <Payor>
                    <ResponsibleParty>
                        <AccountNumber>YOUR ACCOUNT</AccountNumber>
                        <Contact>
                            <CompanyName>Company Name</CompanyName>
                            <PhoneNumber>1234567890</PhoneNumber>
                        </Contact>
                        <Address>
                            <StreetLines>3240 BAYSHORE BLVD</StreetLines>
                            <City>BRISBANE</City>
                            <StateOrProvinceCode>CA</StateOrProvinceCode>
                            <PostalCode>94005</PostalCode>
                            <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                        </Address>
                    </ResponsibleParty>
                </Payor>
            </ShippingChargesPayment>
            <CustomsClearanceDetail>
                <CustomsValue>
                    <Currency>USD</Currency>
                    <Amount>17.55</Amount>
                </CustomsValue>
                <Commodities>
                    <Name>TG11</Name>
                    <NumberOfPieces>1</NumberOfPieces>
                    <Description>TG11</Description>
                    <CountryOfManufacture>US</CountryOfManufacture>
                    <Weight>
                        <Units>KG</Units>
                        <Value>16.2</Value>
                    </Weight>
                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                    <QuantityUnits>EA</QuantityUnits>
                    <UnitPrice>
                        <Currency>USD</Currency>
                        <Amount>17.55</Amount>
                    </UnitPrice>
                    <CustomsValue>
                        <Currency>USD</Currency>
                        <Amount>17.55</Amount>
                    </CustomsValue>
                    <PartNumber>TG11</PartNumber>
                </Commodities>
            </CustomsClearanceDetail>
            <LabelSpecification>
                <LabelFormatType>COMMON2D</LabelFormatType>
                <ImageType>PDF</ImageType>
                <LabelStockType>PAPER_7X4.75</LabelStockType>
            </LabelSpecification>
            <RateRequestTypes>LIST</RateRequestTypes>
            <RateRequestTypes>ACCOUNT</RateRequestTypes>
            <PackageCount>1</PackageCount>
            <RequestedPackageLineItems>
                <Weight>
                    <Units>LB</Units>
                    <Value>39.683</Value>
                </Weight>
                <Dimensions>
                    <Length>10</Length>
                    <Width>20</Width>
                    <Height>30</Height>
                    <Units>IN</Units>
                </Dimensions>
                <SpecialServicesRequested>
                    <SpecialServiceTypes>SIGNATURE_OPTION</SpecialServiceTypes>
                    <SignatureOptionDetail>
                        <OptionType>DIRECT</OptionType>
                    </SignatureOptionDetail>
                </SpecialServicesRequested>
                <ContentRecords>
                    <PartNumber>TG11</PartNumber>
                    <ItemNumber>TG11</ItemNumber>
                    <ReceivedQuantity>1</ReceivedQuantity>
                    <Description>Trad.Good 11,PD,Reg.Trading</Description>
                </ContentRecords>
            </RequestedPackageLineItems>
        </RequestedShipment>
    </ProcessShipmentRequest>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ProcessShipmentReply xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v13">
        <HighestSeverity>ERROR</HighestSeverity>
        <Notifications>
            <Severity>ERROR</Severity>
            <Source>ship</Source>
            <Code>2464</Code>
            <Message>Invalid service type.</Message>
            <LocalizedMessage>Invalid service type.</LocalizedMessage>
        </Notifications>
        <Notifications>
            <Severity>WARNING</Severity>
            <Source>ship</Source>
            <Code>2469</Code>
            <Message>shipTimestamp is invalid</Message>
            <LocalizedMessage>shipTimestamp is invalid</LocalizedMessage>
        </Notifications>
        <TransactionDetail>
            <CustomerTransactionId>J-0080000190-12345671000000128</CustomerTransactionId>
        </TransactionDetail>
        <Version>
            <ServiceId>ship</ServiceId>
            <Major>13</Major>
            <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
            <Minor>0</Minor>
        </Version>
    </ProcessShipmentReply>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Answer (score 0):

After checking the developer guide of FedEx web services, the "SAMEDAY" and "SAMEDAYCITY" services can only be used for intra-Mexico. I was trying to use it for intra-USA.

For more information, please refer FedEx developer guide.